# Send Firebase automatic collected event to Google Analytics through GTM

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I have a question about sending Firebase events to Google Analytics through Google Tag Manager.

It's okay with custom events, all works perfectly.

But it's not working for automatic colleted events in Firebase like "app_remove" or "first_open".

I tried by creating a specific tag (in GTM) with the variables etc... but it's not sending the data to Google Analytics.

Do I have to configure it in a specific way ?

Best regards,

Romain